# How can I set up automated monthly email reports?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, civicontribute, upgrade

I'm aiming to automate the monthly email distribution of a report. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

On the report, click the Email Delivery tab, fill out the details there and set up a Scheduled Job to send it monthly (you'll find instructions if you click the little ? icon beside Email Delivery Settings).